# Can i use dataflow import to update products in Magento

Tags: magento, csv, product

I am really sorry for asking this. I feel like this is a stupid question, but honestly I have googled until the term googling has lost all meaning.

I just want to do a bulk update of product information, I do not want to add or import new products, just update the information for existing products. But all I seem to be able to find on google is articles referring to importing products into Magento. Perhaps my google-fu is failing me, and if this is the case I apologize, but I would be grateful if someone can just answer this really simple question.

I have a CSV file with updated product information.

I want to use this file to update the existing products in Magento 1.9.x.

Can this be done with importing?

Or will I have to build a script that reads the CSV file and manually updates each product?

Comment: If anyone else is wondering the same thing - so far my conclusion is "No, Dataflow cannot be used to update products".... if you know better please let me know!

Answer (score 2):

Magento uses **sku** as identifier to update records. so you have to use magento structure. At the first you have to export products as a csv file to catch the structure and then modify that as you need. Magento import/export tool is very easy and useful.

**For more details check this out:**

http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/content/store-operations/data-transfer-manage.html

http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/content/store-operations/dataflow.html